# log4j error when uninstalling weblogic

Tags: java, log4j, weblogic, uninstallation

When I'm trying to uninstall weblogic in console mod (failure at uninstallation with GUI mode before !) with this command

```
sh uninstall.sh -mode=console
```

Below is the exception that I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Layout
at com.bea.plateng.common.util.logging.LogFactory.newLogInstance(LogFactory.java:102)
at com.bea.plateng.common.util.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:87)
at com.bea.plateng.wizard.WizardController.setupWizardLog(WizardController.java:325)
at com.bea.plateng.wizard.WizardController.<init>(WizardController.java:168)
at com.bea.plateng.wizard.WizardHelper.invokeWizard(WizardHelper.java:161)
at com.bea.plateng.wizard.WizardHelper.invokeWizardAndWait(WizardHelper.java:42)
at com.bea.plateng.wizard.WizardController.main(WizardController.java:933)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Layout
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

I took google search many times but no luck.

Many thanks for helping me solve this issue.

Comment: 'uninstall.sh' should be referring to log4j jar. Can you find that line in script?

Comment: I took a look at uninstall.sh file in 
/home/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/uninstall.

But it contains just only few lines

#!/bin/sh

# Set WebLogic Home
DIRNAME=`dirname $0`/..
WL_HOME=`cd ${DIRNAME} && pwd`
export WL_HOME

"/home/Oracle/Middleware/utils/uninstall/uninstall.sh" $*

exit $?

Comment: Try placing log4j.jar in DOMAIN_NAME/lib

Comment: The error is still there :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your end target is to just uninstall weblogic, you may opt to just manually delete relevant directories. If you wish to stick to script or GUI , you might try to solve log4j issue logically,

1. Place log4j jar in $DOMAIN_NAME/lib
2. If uninstall script is looking for log4j that means a java process might be getting called from some other nested script and that is trying to use log4j to write logs. Try to provide log4j jar via -cp command to that process
3. Do your startWeblogic & stopWeblogic scripts able to use log4j successfully? if yes, try to provide log4j path to uninstall in same way as done in those scripts

You have to mainly figure out as why your uninstall.sh is looking for log4j.

Its hard to answer precisely since these issues are very much machine specific. If you are going with manual delete option, google for steps specific to your OS.

Comment: Finally, I deleted the relevant directories :D. Simplest solution. Thank for sharing